# How to configure log4j properties file for run on command line?

Tags: log4j, sbt

I'm using sbt to compile a project, and am using `slf4j-log4j` for logging. My `log4j.properties` file is not on classpath -- it's in `conf/log4j.properties`.

I would like to run my project on command line with `sbt run`, and configure the log4j file. I have already tried

```
sbt "run -Dlog4j.configuration=conf/log4j.properties"
sbt "run -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///conf/log4j.properties"
```

and several other variations, which always give me the same warning,

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out this is not possible due to a bug with sbt. https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1041

Comment: I don't think the issue pertain to your case. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on how you run your applications in sbt that's controlled by `fork` setting.

```
> help fork
If true, forks a new JVM when running.  If false, runs in the same JVM as the build.
```

With `fork` set to `false`, you have to pass `-D`'s to sbt process itself with `SBT_OPTS` that effectively sets the Java properties for the entire build.

With `fork` set to `true`, you can use `javaOptions`:

```
> help javaOptions
Options passed to a new JVM when forking.
```